# Salesforce Email Attachment settings in metadata

Tags: email, salesforcedx

Is there any way to view and edit the Salesforce Email Attachment Settings (UI Setup -> Email -> Email Attachments) in the Orgs metadata, and if so, in which file and path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific setting will be stored in SfdcOrganizationValues.I've checked with the Salesforce team that owns this feature and confirmed that it is not exposed through any API currently. You can also observe that there is no mention of this setting in the [Metadata Coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/51) too.

The only viable option is to choose/ update the Email Attachment settings through setup UI.

Comment: Thanks Swetha! I cannot open the report you linked, unfortunately, but the information itself is valuable enough to me!

Comment: Apologies. I corrected the hyperlink in the answer to reflect https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/51